# ¿Cómo surgió la expresión "tener su aquel"?

Tags: historia, sustantivos, pronombres-demostrativos

El demostrativo *aquel* parece tener un uso como sustantivo en la locución adverbial *tener su aquel*, recogida por el DLE de la siguiente forma:

> **[tener su aquel](https://dle.rae.es/aquel)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. Dicho de una persona: Tener cierto interés o atractivo indefinible. *Juana tiene su aquel.*
> 2. loc. verb. Dicho de un asunto: Tener cierta complejidad no evidente. *Parecía resuelto, pero el asunto tiene su aquel.*

En 1726 este uso no aparece en el *Autoridades*, que cita solo los casos habituales más uno en el que se usa para reforzar la primera persona ("yo soy aquel que..."). De hecho en el CORDE los primeros casos son del siglo XIX, así que tiene que ser una creación relativamente reciente.

> *Pues digo, si tendrá su aquel la comisioncita.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Miau", 1888 (España).

Veo que en tiempos pasados se usaba *aquel* como demostrativo precedido de *su*, en frases como la siguiente:

> *Nombró la reina por sus testamentarios a don Juan de Gues prior de Roncesvalles y a don Juan de Gúrpide canceller de Navarra y a Dionís Coscón capitán general de su aquel reino [...].*
>
> Jerónimo Zurita, "Anales de la corona de Aragón. Segunda parte", 1579 (España).

No sé si tendrá algo que ver, pero en todo caso, ¿cómo y cuándo surgió el uso de *aquel* como sustantivo en la expresión *tener su aquel*?

Answer (score 5):

En sus *[Estudios Practicos de Buen Decir y de Arcanidades del Habla Espanola](https://digibug.ugr.es/handle/10481/48985?locale-attribute=es)* (1879), **Adolfo de Castro** escribe (página 331):

> *Tener mucho aquel* es tener mucho entendimiento ó mucha in­teligencia, *aqeul*, palabra adquirida de los moros mismos.

Según Wikipedia, *[Aqeel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqeel)* es un nombre árabe que, en efecto, significa "sabio" o "inteligente".